# Upload a new version to app store?

Tags: ios, app-store

I downloaded the source code of my app from github which was built by someone else. Now I have made quite a few changes in the app. To test the app on my iphone, I changed the bundle id, codesigning, provisioning profile etc. Now the issue is how do I update my app on the appstore? Do I need to download any provisioning profiles or any other files to upload safely? How do I code sign the app again so that no problems occur? 
Kindly help.

Comment: What have you tried? What changes from the last time you submitted?What is and isn't working?

Comment: Who owns the iPhone dev centre accounts and iTunes connect? Is it not you? If yes, use the same bundle id as in iTunes connect,  set up the apple account with Xcode, and try building

Comment: I own the itunes connect account. Don't I need to download any provisioning profiles? Will just using the same bundle id suffice? 

Also, when I use the same bundle id, it says no matching profiles found.

Comment: Did you upload the app before on your iTunes store?

Comment: Yes, it was uploaded before too

Answer (score 1):

If App is already created on developer account then you can not change bundle id from it.

You just need to delete that AppId from developer account and create new AppID and assign new bundle id and create certificate, provisional profile from initial.

Answer (score 0):

If you were able to open the app on your XCode and test it on your iPhone device, then you don't have to worry about code-signing. You can create app id, certificate and provisioning profile from scratch and implement them in your project. You just need your apple developer account. 
Legal advice: Make sure that you have enough permission to copy from git and publish app.

Comment: Don't I need to download any sort of provisioning profile??

Comment: Yes. you create your own provisioning profile and download it.

Comment: a. Generate "Certificate Signing Request" (CSR) from Keychain and save it. Export it's private key from keychain and save. 
  b. Developer portal: create a certificate (development / production) using CSR
  c. Developer portal: create provisioning profile using the certificate, download and save it
d. add your account in XCode preferences, 
e. add the provision profile in General tab. 
Actually, it's not easy to mention all the processes here. Just try on google. Or ask another question. I may answer it there - if I find that question.

Answer (score 0):

1.first add your new version in iTunes connect for the particular app.

2.change the same version to your project target.

3.use the same distribution provisional profile for upload your app i.e(latest version)

4.your app name,bundle id ,all are same ,in whats new you need to tell the what features you are added compare to previous version in iTunes Connect.